# Percentage of light less than the critical angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, photons, refraction

I am stuck on the following question:

"Calculate the fraction of the light incident on the surface with an angle less than the critical angle for total internal reflection"

The context of the question is an LED where the refractive index of the semiconductor is 3.40 and the wavelength is 705nm. It also says to assume light is emitted equally in all directions from a single point, and the surface is flat and infinitely wide.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, the following may help point in the right direction.

The first step will be to compute the critical angle for total internal reflection.  The assumption here is that the semiconductor material with the high index of refraction $\left(n=3.4\right)$ is placed in free space $\left(n=1.0\right)$.  Then, one needs to determine that angle at which the refracted ray from the semiconductor to free space will be at $90$ degrees.  The below figure shows the idea, where $\theta$ is the critical angle.

[image]

This $\theta$ can be determined from the usual formula $n_{1}\sin \theta_{1}=n_{2}\sin \theta_{2}$, where $n_{1}=3.4, n_{2}=1.0$, and $\sin \theta_{2}=1$ in this case.

From this point, I believe it should be possible to determine the fraction within that cone (of half-angle $\theta$) compared to the entire hemisphere of light incident on the surface based on sphere geometry.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So if the critical angle is 17.1 degrees, would it just be 17.1 / 360 ?

Comment: No.  Think in terms of the surface area of a sphere, vs the surface area of the "cap" that spans 17 degrees.